# Microsoft Lumia 640 - Missing keyboard and error code 0x80073712

Tags: update, keyboard

I know that I'm not the only person who has  this problem, so i want to ask you how to resolve it. W10 Mobile is here but and problem is here too. I had problem when i update my Lumia 640 from Windows Phone 8.1 to Windows 10 Mobile. First error is in migration data. I had 22 steps but problem is in 14 step in migration, and migration was stopped.  My phone was updated with error and message was show me every time when I power on my phone. I first hour of Windows 10 Mobile my phone was restarted many times without reasons. First i think that it's necessary because many app wait for update in store. While app are upgrading I tried to upgrade the version of system to the.164 but here is first error, download is gone but problem is in the preparation of the installation this step go to 2% and that's it show me this message.

(Some files of updates missing or there is a problem with them. We will try to download update. Error code - 0x80073712)

Then i say ok this will be resolved but when i tried to send text message to my friend about new version of Windows Mobile there is second problem. I don't have keyboard for typing. -.-

Only real solution in that moment for me is hard reset. I was send all my important files to SD Card and do hard reset. It's gone good without error and i say thanks God finally I have good and stable W10M. Because time for sleeping come I was put my Lumia 640 next to my bed to do all apps updates and i was go to sleep. Next day i see that all is gone good, no error, but again I tried to update system from .107 to .164 without success - the same error.

So now i ask all of you how to resolve this problem. I can't go back to Windows Phone 8.1. but i can't go forward?

Answer (score 1):

Check, under **Settings**, that automatic backups are completed successfully. Windows will not perform (non-security) system updates if the backups fail (so that in case the update fails your personal data isn't lost).
Also try choosing the option to perform a manual backup.

Comment: that isn't the problem, backup are completed succesfull

Comment: OK. I hope someone else has a better suggestion then.